# Is there a production ready Lisp-like language on the .NET platform?

Tags: .net, clojure, lisp

I'm looking for a .NET analog to Java's Clojure. I know Clojure has a .NET port, but it looks like it has a long way to go until it catches with the Java version.

I'm currently using F#, but it sometime feels 10 times less productive than a proper List/Scheme.

Comment: Clojure-CLR may be somewhat behind the Java version, but it's still probably the closest thing you'll get to Clojure on the CLR. You can always start using it and contribute patches!

Comment: I would agree with mikera, Clojure CLR seems to be the best choice around and you can check the latest updates at http://clojureclr.blogspot.in

Comment: It's not surprising that F# doesn't approximate Lisp or Scheme very well, since it's the .NET version of OCaml (which is in turn part of the ML family of languages).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wikipedia's page [List of CLI languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_CLI_languages) lists only [IronScheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IronScheme) among Lisps for CLI. I don't know about its production readiness. I guess, you don't have much choice.